# Can't access encrypted sqlite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, vb.net-2010, navicat

I used Navicat Premium to create the database file and selected encrypted to put a password. Now when I try accessing the database in my vb.net program I get an error saying...

> file is encrypted or is not a database

`"Data Source=\\10.10.10.10\Folder\database.db;Password=pwd;Version=3;", True`

The above is my connection string (please ignore the network path =) ). Anyway, I can get through opening the connection but when reading data I get the error. I tried creating another database that doesn't have a password and it worked fine. I even copy pasted the password I have in code to navicat to make sure i typed it correctly.

Comment: Do not put SQLite databases on network file servers.

Comment: What driver are you using to access SQLite databases from VB.Net? Stock SQLite does not support encryption, so the other tool is likely doing something proprietary and your database driver may not support encryption.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm using the System.Data.SQLite.dll file